# Importing custom font to SAPUI5 application

Tags: css, sapui5, custom-font

I'm playing around an expense app for some look&feel, and would like to use a receipt-like font. So I found the [FakeReceipt](https://www.1001fonts.com/fake-receipt-font.html) font, got my woff and woff2 files at the same directory with my style.css and voila! It works.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FakeReceipt';
    src: url('FakeReceipt.woff') format('woff'),
     url('FakeReceipt.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[image]

Everything works fine on localhost, i am able to see the font loaded correctly, but when i deployed it to the dev server, it shows a warning at console:

- Failed to decode downloaded font: https://*********/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap//~04E3CA24FE6465024E9A6D765A0A6010~5/css/FakeReceipt.woff
  /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?saml2=disabled#ZExpense-create:1
- OTS parsing error: Size of decompressed WOFF 2.0 font exceeds 30MB
- OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header

I can still see it downloads the font at dev tools network tab but but font characters are different from localhost, it is seen like a generic font, and that vaporized the main purpose.

[image]

[image]

I am using personal edition of SAP Webide 1.53.9 64bit, 1.71.13 sapui5 version if it is relevant.

What is causing this? I've tried every different browser i've heard of.

Thanks!

Comment: What dev server are you using? ABAP, SCP, others? It sounds like the font file isn't being served correctly from there. - Scratch that, I saw the URL, how are you uploading the file to the ABAP server? You might need to specify how to handle serving the woff2 file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got NetWeaver Gateway, and i am deploying with personal edition of SAP Webide 1.53.9 64bit, 1.71.13 sapui5 version. The TTF file worked btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A woff2 file is a binary file and I believe the error is caused by the UI5 uploader to ABAP not correctly classifying the file.

To tell the ABAP server that this is a binary file, you need to create a `.Ui5RepositoryBinaryFiles` in the directory you upload to ABAP. This file (along with a corresponding `.Ui5RepositoryTextFiles` file) creates a list of extra extensions that are interpreted as binary or text.

Each line in the file is written like this `^.*\.woff2$` to denote the extensions to include.

More information can be found on the UI5 SDK - https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/a560bd6ed4654fd1b338df065d331872.html

It's also important to note that woff2 isn't supported on IE11 (if you want to support that browser) - https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2. Generally you need to define a chain of supported fonts and the browser stops on the one that it supports.

Comment: Hi @orogers, thanks for the answer. I'll try it at my free time. As it is working right now with ttf, making it work with woff2 is degraded to "nice to have" :) Besides i changed the css with the chain:

`@font-face {
 font-family: 'receiptFont';
 src: url('fonts/fakereceipt.eot');
 src: url('fonts/fakereceipt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/fakereceipt.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/fakereceipt.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/fakereceipt.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}`

Comment: So now, as safari doesn't work with ttf, it is not a nice to have anymore, a must. I am searching about the solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I looked at SE80, theres only the `.ttf` file there. After that i checked console of the localhost webide while uploading, it says isBinary=true only at the `.ttf` file. Sadly when i apply your suggested solution, it still doesn't upload those files as binaries.

Now i am trying the ABAP report to deploy, it is promising with the output right now saying:
...
*  File ".Ui5RepositoryTextFiles" has been considered to identify text files.  *
*  File ".Ui5RepositoryBinaryFiles" has been considered to identify binary files.  *

Comment: Now SE80 shows all 6 font files as binaries. But scene haven't changed, still works good on desktop and android, not good at safari and ios chrome. I'll try to delete the ttf file and upload with /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD again, so maybe my woff2 file is corrupt. Lets check..

Comment: And it is done! The woff2 file i am dealing with was corrupt also. Thanks again for pointing out. Well appreciated ^^